# Is there a way to pass a vector of unknown type as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, vector, c++17

I want to have a function, with any type of vector as my function parameter

```
void vectorFunction(vector <int> vec){
     doSomething;
}
```

However, I need this function to work for a vector of any type;

```
vector<int>
vector<double>
```

but also more complicated types like

```
vector <pair <int, int>>
```

What datatype do I give the function to alow me to pass any vector?

Comment: `template <typename T> void vectorFunction(vector<T> vec) {}`

Comment: Perhaps you need a function template.

Comment: It’s important to think here about what your `doSomething` can be if you want it to work for a (wide) variety of types.

Answer (score 0):

You need generic programming, which is done with templates in C++. A std::vector itself is a template.

To a template function write you you add `template<typename T>` in front of it. `T` is the placeholder for the unknown type.

As Igor Tandetnik wrote in a comment, here is the syntax for your example:

```
template <typename T>
void vectorFunction(vector<T> vec) {
    // do something
}
```

Please note, that you refer in your function to a `vector<T>`. The compiler will instantiate those templates for every type needed.

If you want to know more, please check out https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Comment: Note that the term _template metaprogramming_ is typically not used for templates in general. It's used for stuff like metafunctions that converts types to types (`std::remove_reference`), types to values (`std::is_copy_constructible`), etc.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I just literally translated the German term "Metaprogrammierung" which is used to refer to templates. I replace it with generic